# how to crop image from medialibrary windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have large image in medialibrary (5000 * 5000 pixels). and i need to take only part of the image. let say that it starts at x=200 y=200 and its 1000 pixels widht and height. how can i do that ? i dont have any good solutions for that.

only solution i found:

to use
photochoosertask....
and then

```
var b = new WriteableBitmap(5000, 5000);
 b.LoadJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);
 WriteableBitmap wb = b.Crop(200, 200, 1000, 1000);
 image1.Source = wb
```

but the result is very bad quality and i got some ram issues also...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are creating the WriteableBitmap of size 1000x1000. When you call the LoadJpeg it loads your image to that resolution, which is causing the issues with quality. And when you crop, the things get worse.

Memory issues are kind of normal when you try to work with large pictures. To avoid it, you might be better off using the SetSource method which automatically scales your photo to be under 2000x2000 pixels. If you want to read more about that, you can [find details on my blog](http://igrali.com/2012/01/03/how-to-open-and-work-with-large-photos-on-windows-phone/).

Using the Crop method is the way to go, though. Steps to take include:

- Create BitmapImage from stream source and then a WriteableBitmap from it (or, alternatively, create a WriteableBitmap of size 5000,5000 which is what you want, but will cause you memory issues)
- call the Crop method, but scale everything to match the resolution that you get when using SetSource - should be 2000x2000 or less.
- Set image1.Source to the newly created WB.

Comment: uups. i made an error while writing that code (Now its right). I have tried that setsource method but it breaks image quality becauce it scale my photo under 2000*2000. if I use loadjpeg method my photo is 5000*5000 but quality of the image is still bad.

Comment: 5000x5000 means 95MB in memory. When cropping you create a new WriteableBitmap which is also large, and you will have a lot of memory issues. Are you sure you need that size? What is the size of the image1 Image element? Maybe you should share some screenshots, not sure what a bad quality means in your case (stretched picture, pixelated picture etc.)